# How do I get a test account to try out SagePay on Drupal Commerce

Tags: drupal, opayo

My client wants me to set up a "demo" of Drupal Commerce making payments to SagePay. (using Drupal 7). How do I do this without registering a "live" SagePay account, or at least, without registering a SagePay account that you have to pay for?

Answer (score -1):

I can set this up for you in less than 5 minutes - just how to share the credentials? (obviously, I'm not keen on putting them up here)

Comment: Thanks for the offer Rik - actually I've just spoken to SagePay support this morning and they have given me some credentials for a test account. It does seem that it was not possible to set up a test account through any "self-service" option on their website, and their support team had to do this - is this your understanding also, or was there some procedure I could have gone through to set one up for myself?

Comment: There isn't a self service option, unfortunately - I work for SP and can create accounts by 'other means'!